# jqgrid error - b.jgrid.jqID is not a function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to get started with the jQuery plugin, jqGrid, however it's giving me the error - "b.jgrid.jqID is not a function". I downloaded the plugin from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 with all features included and am referencing both jquery.jqGrid.min.js and grid.locale-en.js.

Here is the html:

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

And here is the js:

```
jQuery(function () {

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/admin/campus/getnearbybusinesses',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Name', 'Location'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150 },
                { name: 'Location', index: 'Location', width: 150 }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'Name',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Businesses"
        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

    });
```

Comment: Issue ending up being that I had referenced jqgrid .js first when grid.locale-en.js needs to be referenced first.

Comment: You're my hero.  I've been working this issue for two hours thinking I had an error in my script.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please try to include "i18n/grid.locale-en.js" 
before "jquery.jqGrid.src.js"

Comment: I posted the answer in my comment 8 days before this answer but I'll give you the points. :)

Comment: This also helps for error `object has no method jqID`. Just put it here for Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so first thing you need to consider is order of the included scripts (ex. first you need to load `jquery`, then grid.locale, and the last `jqgrid.min.js`), second thing to be considered is multiple included `javascripts`(in my project this was the problem, i have included `jqgrid` in two places).
I removed them all and kept, only 1 version and the code started working file.