# Error: $.jgrid. is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I play my PHP/JS project in Firefox some errors happen and the grids often do not load.

The errors – shown by Firebug – are each time different in number and type.

For example…

… on first start…

```
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
restoreRow : function(rowid, afterrestorefunc) {
```

… after pressing F5…

no error happens

… after a further F5…

```
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
getChangedCells : function (mthd) {
grid.celledit.js (riga 448)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
toggleSubGridRow : function(rowid) {
grid.subgrid.js (riga 265)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
addChildNode : function( nodeid, parentid, data ) {
grid.treegrid.js (riga 545)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
"avg" : function(v, field, rc) {
grid.grouping.js (riga 286)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
filterToolbar : function(p){
grid.custom.js (riga 128)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
excelExport : function(o) {
grid.import.js (riga 179)
$.jgrid.extend is not a function
gridResize : function(opts) {
grid.jqueryui.js (riga 471)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
n=0,p;for(p=0;p<a.p.colModel.length;p+…a.p.id)+" tbody:first tr:first")[0];
jquery….min.js (riga 54)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
M),I={};G=G.slice((N-1)*M,N*M);n=w=nul…load_"+b.jgrid.jqID(a.p.id)).hide();
jquery….min.js (riga 75)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
M),I={};G=G.slice((N-1)*M,N*M);n=w=nul…load_"+b.jgrid.jqID(a.p.id)).hide();
jquery….min.js (riga 75)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
M),I={};G=G.slice((N-1)*M,N*M);n=w=nul…load_"+b.jgrid.jqID(a.p.id)).hide();
jquery….min.js (riga 75)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
n=0,p;for(p=0;p<a.p.colModel.length;p+…a.p.id)+" tbody:first tr:first")[0];
jquery….min.js (riga 54)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
n=0,p;for(p=0;p<a.p.colModel.length;p+…a.p.id)+" tbody:first tr:first")[0];
jquery….min.js (riga 54)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
n=0,p;for(p=0;p<a.p.colModel.length;p+…a.p.id)+" tbody:first tr:first")[0];
jquery….min.js (riga 54)
b.jgrid.jqID is not a function
M),I={};G=G.slice((N-1)*M,N*M);n=w=nul…load_"+b.jgrid.jqID(a.p.id)).hide();
```

… and after a further F5…

other 15 similar errors happen.

In the main page of the project I included the libraries as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>      
      <title></title>        
      <link type="text/css" href="js/jquery/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="js/jqGrid/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
      <script src="js/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/jqGrid/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'd like to know what's wrong. Thanks,

Comment: Do you put your javascript code in the jquery ready function?  `<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() { myJavascriptCode(); }); </script>`

Comment: Hallo Geoffroy, I did as you advised me... but the errors continue to appear :-(

Comment: Ok. Do you really need the `grid.loader.js`? normally in the last version of jqgrid, we don't need it. (In my project I don't have it).

Comment: See the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970600/jqgrid-error-b-jgrid-jqid-is-not-a-function

I think it might be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try and paste the link to the grid js file in the browser's address bar (prepended with the address of your site):

```
[http://localhost/YourSite]/js/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

and see if it displays the js script. If not - it means the address is wrong, and the grid does not load (and $.jgrid does not exist then).

Comment: I did as you advised me and the browser showed the script... so the address is OK. The strange thing is that on Explorer the project plays without problems (errors). Is there something wrong with the including order?