# jqGrid and MVC3 url action method does not get called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I can't get the jqGrid to call my action method on my controller. I'm completely new to this, so I'm probably making a lot of newbie mistakes. I've taken samplecode from jqGrids documentation and modified it a bit.

Code in the view:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetContactRows", "Contact")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Name', 'Address', 'City'],
        colModel: [
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80 },
          { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 80 },
          { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 80 }
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'invid',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'List of Contacts'
    });
});
```

Code in the controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetContactRows(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool search, string filters)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asdf");

        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

I've set a breakpoint in my controller action method, but I just can't get it to hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter must be called `_search`, not `search`. Also you don't seem to be passing any JSON data. Here's an example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetContactRows(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters)
    {
        var data = new
        {
            page = 1,
            total = 1,
            records = 3,
            rows = new[]
            {
                new 
                {
                    id = 1,
                    cell = new[] { "Name 1", "Address 1", "City 1" },
                },
                new 
                {
                    id = 2,
                    cell = new[] { "Name 2", "Address 2", "City 2" },
                },
                new 
                {
                    id = 3,
                    cell = new[] { "Name 3", "Address 3", "City 3" },
                }
            }
        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Notice the action signature using `_search` as parameter name and also notice that we allow GET requests by using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` when returning the JSON.

and the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetContactRows", "Home")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Name', 'Address', 'City'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80 },
              { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 80 },
              { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 80 }
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'invid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: 'List of Contacts'
        });
    }); 
</script>

<table id="list"></table>
```

---

`<rant>`

Also to be able to easily debug those kind of problems please use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug. It allows you to see all AJAX requests in your browser as well as what the server sends as response. If you had done that you would have immediately seen this error.

It took me exactly 70 seconds, to go to the jqGrid web site, download it, create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application, copy-paste your code, reference jqGrid that I have previously downloaded, hit F5 to run the application, hit F12 in FireFox to open FireBug, see that the AJAX request that jqGrid attempted to perform was shown in red (because the server returned HTTP 500 status code), click on the + sign next to this AJAX request and read the exact exception message sent by the server telling me that it cannot find a value for the `search` parameter which is a non nullable boolean, click on the `Params` tab and see the exact parameters sent by the client:

[image]

Do you see how trivially easy is to do web development when you use the right tools? 70 seconds. It's faster than asking a question on StackOverflow.

`</rant>`

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. I also came across this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970600/jqgrid-error-b-jgrid-jqid-is-not-a-function. I agree on your <rant>, my problem is that I'm not allowed to install any other browser than IE. However, F12-mode helped in a similar way.

Comment: @kaze, you are not allowed to install any other browser than IE? And they expect from you to do web development? Are you working for the Inquisition? Were you punished for doing something wrong?

Comment: That's the way it is - I'm working on getting the rules to change to allow us to install FF and some other "must-have"-tools.

Comment: @kaze: Small remark only. If you want to use `search` instead of `_search` parameter which more corresponds to the name conversion, you can use additional jqGrid option `prmNames: { search: "search"}`. Using [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option you can rename almost all parameters which send jqGrid to the server.