# jqGrid - TypeError: "#List".jqGrid is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code in a separate script file in my project for populating jqGrid.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    ("#List").jqGrid({
    url: '/Dept/Index/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Name'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300, align: 'left'}],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortOrder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Dept List'
    });
});
```

When I run the project, I observe the following error in Firebug's console. TypeError: `"#List".jqGrid is not a function`.

If I  however embed the script within a file, the error disappears. I have followed the instructions on [how to install](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install) and also looked at answers to [similar errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970600/jqgrid-error-b-jgrid-jqid-is-not-a-function) and I am certain that I have jqgrid.js and grid.locale-en.js in the proper order.

How can I eliminate this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
$("#List")
```

or:

```
jQuery("#List")
```

You can read about it here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

The result of `("#List")` is just a String, which is why the interpreter claims there is no method called `jqGrid`.